# How do I convert Flux<Object> to Flux<ObjectDto> to Mono<ListOfDto>?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I have a problem with data conversion in reactive Spring. I have two dtos: `ObjectDto` and `ListOfDtos` that has a constructor `ListOfDtos(List<ObjectDto> dtos)`. There are also mapper `ObjectMapper`:

```java
public static Mono<ObjectDto> toObjectDto(Object object) {
    return Mono.just(object)
        .map(o - > new ObjectDto(o.getField1(), o.getField2(), ...));
}
```

In the service, I have to get a list of objects by field and return ListOfDtos. How can I do this?

The most I could achieve was to return `Flux<ObjectDto>` but I need to return `Mono<ListOfDtos>`

```java
public Flux<ObjectDto> getAllObjectsByField(String field) {
    return Mono.just(field)
        .flatMapMany(field - > objectRepository.findByField(field))
        .flatMap(ObjectMapper::toObjectDto);
}
```

I will be grateful for your help!

Comment: you can apply this to the Flux<ObjectDto> which you acquired in your second method: `.collectList().map(ListOfDtos::new)`

Comment: The code seems to be a bit convoluted. I think your whole code could be solved by: `objectRepository.findByField(field).map(o -> new ObjectDto(o.get...)).collectList().map(ListOfDtos::new)` (where you obviously need to fill out the constructor of ObjectDto).